# Scrapy: NameError: global name 'MyItem' is not defined

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to fill my Items with parsed data and I'm getting error: **NameError: global name 'QuotesItem' is not defined**
when trying to run **$ scrapy crawl quotes**

Here's my spider's code:

quotes.py:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
start_urls = [
        'http://www.successories.com/iquote/category/39/inspirational-quotes/4',
        'http://www.successories.com/iquote/category/39/inspirational-quotes/6',
        'http://www.successories.com/iquote/category/39/inspirational-quotes/7',
        'http://www.successories.com/iquote/category/39/inspirational-quotes/8',
        'http://www.successories.com/iquote/category/39/inspirational-quotes/9',
        ]

def parse(self,response):
  items = []
  for quote in response.css('div.quotebox'):
    item = QuotesItem()
    item['quoteAuthor'] =  quote.css('div.quote a::text').extract_first()
    item['quoteText'] = quote.css('div.quote a::text').extract_first()
    items.append(item)
    yield items
```

Here's my items code
items.py:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesItem(scrapy.Item):
    quoteAuthor = scrapy.Field()
    quoteText = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: you need to `import` `QuotesItem` to `quotes.py`'s namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `QuotesItem` in another file called `items.py`. Now you have to [import](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html) either the entire module `items` or just the `QuotesItem`. Add the following to the top of your `quotes.py`:

```
from items import QuotesItem
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I'm solving a problem with module Items :D, but I'll try to google it.